# NodeJS App Deployment - NPM/Gulp

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-web-services, gulp, aws-code-deploy

I'm attempting to deploy a nodeJS app on AWS CodeDeploy, and have an issue with gulp dependencies and running npm install/start from a bash file.

I have a standard app folder structure, with package.json in the project root etc.

**Bash file (bin/npm_install.sh)**

```
cd /opt/deployments/app-backend
npm install
```

**NPM script definitions**

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "gulp minify-sdk && gulp setup-auto",
  "start": "gulp",
  "test": "gulp test"
}
```

**Error when running bin/npm_install.sh**

```
[stdout]
[stdout]> app@0.0.1 start /opt/deployments/app-backend
[stdout]> gulp
[stdout]
[stderr]
[stderr]module.js:340
[stderr]    throw err;
[stderr]          ^
[stderr]Error: Cannot find module 'pretty-hrtime'
[stderr]    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
[stderr]    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
[stderr]    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
[stderr]    at require (module.js:380:17)
[stderr]    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/deployments/app-backend/node_modules/.bin/gulp:5:18)
[stderr]    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[stderr]    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
[stderr]    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
[stderr]    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[stderr]    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
[stderr]npm ERR! weird error 8
[stderr]npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
[stderr]npm WARN For further explanations, please read
[stderr]/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
[stderr] 
[stderr]npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

NOTE: Running npm install works fine from the project root folder.

Any suggestions? Is this the best way to start the app after codedeploy has finished deploying the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I haven't discovered an explanation for this, the issue was that when the node_modules folder was being returned from TravisCI/CodeShip, the node_modules/.bin/* files did not have symlinks so those modules could not resolve their internal dependencies.

I ended up resolving this by running npm install gulp in the after_install hook which recreated the symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'AfterInstall' lifecycle event to install your modules and use 'ApplicationStart' lifecycle event to start the app. Does manually running npm_install.sh succeed?

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of what happened.